# C++ Why use an implicit conversion from (std::string) to (void) type?

Tags: c++, networking, type-conversion

I'm looking at CPP-NETLIB's source code and came across this syntax where it describes the concepts.

```
template <class R> struct ClientRequest : network::Message<R> {
  BOOST_CONCEPT_USAGE(ClientRequest) {
    std::string tmp;
    R request_(tmp);
    swap(request, request_);  // swappable via ADL

    std::string host_ = host(request);
    boost::uint16_t port_ = port(request);
    std::string path_ = path(request);
    std::string query_ = query(request);
    std::string anchor_ = anchor(request);
    std::string protocol_ = protocol(request);

    request << uri(std::string());

    network::http::uri(request, std::string());

    (void) host_;
    (void) port_;
    (void) path_;
    (void) query_;
    (void) anchor_;
    (void) protocol_;
  }

 private:
  R request;
};
```

I can't seem to find any explanations that describe how the (void) conversion of in-scope types could be necessary or what it would do. Why would you need to clear the stack before ending the BOOST_CONCEPT_USAGE member function? What else would it do if not clearing the stack?

Comment: It's *explicit*, not implicit...

Comment: and it will not clear the stack.

Comment: Define an macro to do it and name it as "UNUSED_VARIABLE", will fully resolve this confuse.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's just for suppressing the compiler's warnings about unused variable, nothing special.

It does NOT clear the stack in any way, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about it. For host_, the equivalent to (void)host_ is static_cast<void>(host_) here but correct my reasoning: the reason it doesn't suppress anything is because the value isn't saved back into host_?

Comment: @etcimon - nothing is about saving here. `(void)host_;` does not change save anything into `host_`, too. The warning is for `unused parameter/variable` - making `(void)host_;` you actually _use_ it - so this suppresses the warning.

Comment: I went to get some groceries, and I couldn't stop thinking about this... What could be the possible usage of this? I mean, why programmer just didn't comment out the lines?

Comment: @NemanjaBoric - If these lines are removed, then there will be warnings and some projects are compiled with the `-Werror`flag, which means - each warning is considered an error and then the compiling process will fail. There are other ways to avoid this, but it depends on the situation (for example, you may have `void f( int ) { ... }` (note the missing name of the parameter)

Comment: @KirilKirov Yes, I understand that, but I don't understand `std::string protocol_ = ...`. Will  this actually generate fields?

Comment: @NemanjaBoric - what fields? This looks like an example for me. I have no idea what is this function, but maybe it demonstrates something and it's expected, that `protocol_` and the others will be used later for something. The useless may be removed, things like this. I don't know what's the idea, could be just demonstrating the API or something.

Comment: @KirilKirov I think you're right. I just thought `BOOST_CONCEPT_USAGE` is doing some code-generation magic, as I can't find lot of docs on that.

Comment: @NemanjaBoric `BOOST_CONCEPT_USAGE` I think the name says enough :)